# Visual Studio 2017 Shortcut to Fonts and Colors

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, colors, visual-studio-2017

Is there an easy way to add a shortcut to the toolbar (or elsewhere) to go straight to the options->editor->fonts and colors section?

Comment: Such questions are not encouraged, please refrain from asking such questions in future.. have a look on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-button solution, but you can press <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> to set focus to the global search, type `color` or `font` or maybe a substring of each, and the Tools/Options page will be the top search result.  Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and wait for the dialog to load.

Answer (score 0):

See [Opening an Options Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826083.aspx) documentation on how to access it programmatically.

With my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension you can create the following command for it:

(References: System.Design)

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    string fontsAndColorsGUID = "57F6B7D2-1436-11D1-883C-0000F87579D2";
    var command = new System.ComponentModel.Design.CommandID(
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.GUID_VSStandardCommandSet97,
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.cmdidToolsOptions);
    var serviceProvider = package as System.IServiceProvider;
    var mcs = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OleMenuCommandService)serviceProvider.GetService(
        typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.IMenuCommandService));
    mcs.GlobalInvoke(command, fontsAndColorsGUID);
}
```